# Can a vector be sliced linearly?

Tags: vectors

There is a vector
A = [ 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]
and another vector
B = [ 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
that signifies which indices/columns of A are to be extracted.

Is there a linear, vector operation that would yield
C = [1, 8, 13]?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please use the [mathjax basic tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and review the [meta read](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and enhance your question. It helps to include context (i.e., your attempts, motivation, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$M=\begin{bmatrix}
 0&0&0 \\
 1&0&0 \\
 0&0&0 \\
 0&0&0 \\
 0&0&0 \\
 0&0&0 \\
 0&1&0 \\
 0&0&1
 \end{bmatrix}$$

where $M$ is obtained by decomposing $B$ into a sum of unit vectors and using the unit vectors to populate the columns of $M$.

Multiplying on the left by $A$ gives $C$.